# Sync server time

Tags: unix, time, ntp

I have 3 servers and each one of them is showing different time.
How do I correctly set the SAME time across all severs? I noticed that ntpd server is stopped. So I started it.

service ntpd start

Is it the correct way to sync time? (Indian Standard Time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track: edit your ntp.conf file to use the following servers (probably best for you):

```
   server 0.asia.pool.ntp.org
   server 1.asia.pool.ntp.org
   server 2.asia.pool.ntp.org
   server 3.asia.pool.ntp.org
```

Put the same servers in /etc/ntp/step-tickers and restart ntpd on all servers. That is all you need.

Use the same configuration files on all servers, of course

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps make sure NTP clients are running periodically on all three servers and they are pointing to the same NTP server to sync time.

Comment: Might also want to stop ntpd once and run ntpdate against your chosen time server to make an initial correction, then start ntpd to have it do it's thing.